# Python conditionally remove whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove whitespaces in a string that are adjacent to `/` while keeping the rest of the whitespaces.

For instance, say I have a string `98 / 100 xx 3/ 4 and 5/6`. The desired result for my example would be `98/100 xx 3/4 and 5/6`. (So that I could use `.split(' ')` as a next step and extract those meaningful numbers, i.e.`98/100`, `3/4`, and `5/6` as my final results.) Note: I only want to look for `/`, no need to worry other operators.

I know I should probably use `re` for this, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

---------------------My Approach Below------------------

I used `[index_num.end(0) for index_num in re.finditer('/', test)]`, where `test = '98 / 100 xx 3/ 4 and 5/6'` to find the index of the `/`, then check if the previous or the next is a whitespace. That's not ideal and I believe there are easier ways.

Comment: `but I can't figure it out` <- show us what you've tried, and we'll show you what you're missing ;]

Comment: what is xx supposed to be and do you just want to replace the space between digits and any operators? Also it is probably easier just extract the *meaningful numbers*.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I used `[index_num.end(0) for index_num in re.finditer('/', test)]`  to find the index of the `/`, then check if the previous or the next is a whitespace. That's not idea and I believe there are easier ways. Will edit my question and add these, thanks!

Comment: @Chianti5, you still did not clarify if you only want to look for `/` or more operators, if there are more then it is a lot more complicated.

Comment: @Chianti5: what is `index_num`? what is `test`? Please edit your original post to include the code that you've tried, and the incorrect behavior thereof

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you! Yeah I should have made my example clearer. `xx` stands for some words. I was trying to simplify my example but I did a poor job... I only want to look for this single operator `/`.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my question, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove whitespace before and after slashes with `str.replace` instead of regex:

```
>>> '98 / 100 xx 3/ 4 and 5/6'.replace(' /','/').replace('/ ','/')
'98/100 xx 3/4 and 5/6'
```

Comment: This would fail for `'98 /   100 xx 3/ 4 and 5/6'.replace(' /','/').replace('/ ','/')` or any string with more than one space between the number and `/`

Answer (score 3):

A hint: A regular expression that will find any amount of whitespace (not just space characters, but also tabs, etc.) around a slash is: `r'\s*/\s*'`. The regex there is between the apostrophes. The period is just the end of my sentence, and the r tells Python to treat the string inside apostrophes as a "raw" string.

If you don't want to find arbitrary whitespace characters, but only the space character itself, the regex is `r' */ *'`. Note the space in front of the asterisk.

The rest I leave to you, since this sounds like a homework problem.